# Magento 2 ; How to pass custom params with save button in UI Form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

I want to pass a value/params via the save button of my **ui adminform**.

i tried this:

```
public function getButtonData()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
        $id = $request->getParam('id');

        return
            [
                'label' => __('Save'),
                'class' => 'save primary',
                'on_click' => '',
                'sort_order' => 80,
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter' => [
                            'actions' => [
                                [
                                    'targetName' => 'thechateau_magenest_bookable_save',
                                    'actionName' => 'save',
                                    'params' => [
                                        true,
                                        ['multidome_id' =>$id],
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],

                ]
            ];
    }
```

I can indeed see the values in the save button of the phtml page.

```
<button id="save" title="Save" type="button" class="action- scalable save primary" data-mage-init="{&quot;Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/button-adapter&quot;:{&quot;actions&quot;:[{&quot;targetName&quot;:&quot;thechateau_magenest_bookable_save&quot;,&quot;actionName&quot;:&quot;save&quot;,&quot;params&quot;:[true,{&quot;multidome_id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}]}]}}"  data-ui-id="save-button" >
    <span>Save</span>
</button>
```

however when i try to retreive these values it comes up null.

```
$request = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');


$multiDome = $request->getParam('multidome_id');
```

i also tried to add it as part of the URL of the save button but it does not even show up on this:

```
public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save',['param'=>'value']);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used **ButtonProviderInterface**

```
namespace MyVendor\Logger\Block\Adminhtml\Log\Index;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class ImportButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Import Log'),
            'class' => 'action-secondary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'logger_log_listing.logger_log_listing.import_modal',
                                'actionName' => 'openModal'
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'on_click' => '',
            'sort_order' => 20
        ];
    }
}
```

While declaring my button on the listing xml file `logger_log_listing.xml`, like so :

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
...
</argument>
<settings>
        ...
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                ...
            </button>
            <button name="import" class="MyVendor\Logger\Block\Adminhtml\Log\Index\ImportButton"/>
        </buttons>
</settings>
<modal name="import_modal">
...
</modal>
```

PS: I don't know why but not using `'on_click' => ''` resulted in redirection to base url (front page)

Answer (score 0):

Use "getOptions()" method to add custom params. One example:

```
/**
 * Retrieve options
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    $options[] = [
        'id_hard' => 'save_and_new',
        'label' => __('Save & New'),
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'buttonAdapter' => [
                    'actions' => [
                        [
                            'targetName' => 'member_form.member_form',
                            'actionName' => 'save',
                            'params' => [
                                true,
                                [
                                    'back' => 'new'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];

    if (!$this->context->getRequestParam('popup')) {
        $options[] = [
            'label' => __('Save & Duplicate'),
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_duplicate',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'member_form.member_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [
                                    true,
                                    [
                                        'back' => 'duplicate'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    $options[] = [
        'id_hard' => 'save_and_close',
        'label' => __('Save & Close'),
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'buttonAdapter' => [
                    'actions' => [
                        [
                            'targetName' => 'member_form.member_form',
                            'actionName' => 'save',
                            'params' => [
                                true
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks for answer. but how do i add this. do i just place it on the SAVE BUTTON PAGE?

Comment: yes, Add this function to savebutton file. Just after the method "getButtonData".

Comment: does not work. i tried using getParams to get values but it still return null. really grateful if you would help

Comment: Can you share your full code file. I will work on it and share with you the working code.

Comment: no problem. should we go into the chat so that i can share the code . i am not sure how to enter into a one on chat. do u know how to ?

Comment: hi @rahul. i have create a chat room to share my code. here is the link. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97373/magneto2-custom-save-button

Comment: hi @rahui. do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you email me th code to fix and send you back.

Comment: I'm still wondering about why we do this `'targetName' => 'member_form.member_form',` instead of this `'targetName' => 'member_form',`

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code.

```
$this->buttonList->add(
            'select_all',
            [
                'label' => __('Select All Rates and Save'),
                'class' => 'save',
                'onclick' => "jQuery('#testhidden').val(1)",
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save', 'target' => '#edit_form']],

                ]
            ],
            10
        );
```

Create a hidden field in the form.php where fields are defined

```
$fieldset->addField(
                'testhidden',
                'hidden',
                ['name' => 'testhidden', 'value' => 0, 'no_span' => true]
            );
```